# CMD windows running .py scrip not writing to txt file, but running in pycharm does write to the file

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pycharm

```
print("What is this for?:")
z = input(str())
print("Username:")
x = input(str())
print("Password:")
y = input(str())

f = open("UserandPass.txt", 'a')
f.write('\n')
f.write('\n' + 'Domain:')
f.write('\n' + z)
f.write('\n' + 'Username:')
f.write('\n' + x)
f.write('\n' + 'Password:')
f.write('\n' + y)
f.close()

g = open("UserandPassbackup.txt", 'a')
g.write('\n')
g.write('\n' + 'Domain:')
g.write('\n' + z)
g.write('\n' + 'Username:')
g.write('\n' + x)
g.write('\n' + 'Password:')
g.write('\n' + y)
g.close()

print(z)
print(x)
print(y)
```

So I'm running a program in pycharm that can write text to a `.txt` file fine. The issue comes along when I run the `.py` script in the `cmd` prompt... doesn't write to the file. There are no errors, in the `cmd` prompt after running either. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Spaces in filenames are never a good idea, neither is storing passwords and usernames in raw text

Comment: Hmm, I'll edit the file names. How should I store them otherwise  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i run you code in a python3 interpreter under Mac OS, it worked.

maybe it's related to your system, space in the filename may be a problem.

Comment: I took the spaces out, and it still doesn't seem to work. It doesn't give me an error either which is strange

Comment: have you verified the files in the correct location?

the files are created under the path where your script is excuted, not where the script is located.

Comment: Besides the scrip location (location of userpass.py), what else would I enter into the cmd?   This is what I'm entering in the cmd                                           py  C:\Users\genestb\Documents\userpass.py

Comment: your current location.

it seems you use Windows. Type 'cd' to show your current location. The generated files show under current location instead of the script location which is `C:\Users\genestb\Documents\userpass.py`.

you could also run the script in following way:

`cd C:\Users\genestb\Documents\

python userpass.py`


then you should find the txt files under `C:\Users\genestb\Documents\`.

Comment: If i click on the python file scrip to open it directly with cmd, it runs and writes to the txt file fine. Strange, maybe I messed something up while setting up python in the PATH variables.

Comment: there is nothing to do with your PATH configuration.

It's just about under which location python executes the script. When you click on the script, it is executed under the same location as your script.

just try:

`cd C:\Users\genestb\Documents`

then:

`python userpass.py`

Comment: That worked. I put in everything but "python" before userpass.py. Still really new to this, I appreciate the help